# shell - looping command with several variables

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

I'm running an FFmpeg command from a script which takes several arguments and passes them to the command.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "i:b:" flag
do
  case "$flag" in
    i) input="$OPTARG";;
    b) IFS=, read -a bitrate <<< "$OPTARG";;
  esac
done

for rate in "${bitrate[@]}";
  do
    ffmpeg -i $input -video_size 100x100 -b:v $bitrate -y output.mp4
  done

exit
```

I use `getopts` to take the variables and `for` loop to run the command.
To run the script I use `script.sh -i input.mov -b 1000,2000,3000` and FFmpeg runs 3 times, each with different `$bitrate` value.

What if I want to pass another var - scale, to the command and run it like this:
 `script.sh -b 1000,2000,3000 -s 100x100,200x200,300x300` so the first run would use -b 1000 and -s 100x100, second run use -b 2000 and -s 200x200 and so on.
Is this posooble? I would like to keep using getopts if possible.

Comment: This does not answer your question at a technical level, but would it not be easier to have a syntax like :  script.sh 1000.100x100 2000.200x200 3000.300x300.  It seems to me it would be both simpler to code, easier to use, and also allow implicit default values (e.g. scripts.sh 1000, or scripts.sh .100x100).

Comment: Note that you are overwriting `output.mp4` each time through the loop.

Comment: `-video_size` is an input option, not an output option. Use the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) instead: `-vf scale=100:100` or if you prefer something simpler but less flexible you can use `-s 100x100`. Also, assuming you're encoding with libx264, [using `-crf`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) is better than using a specific bitrate unless you're trying to limit the output file size to a specific size (and if that's the case use [two-pass](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass)).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The FFmpeg command above is just to illustrate my question. Though your feedback is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two arrays have the same indices:

```
for i in "${!bitrate[@]}"; do   # i iterates over the indices of bitrate
    ffmpeg -i "$input" -video_size "${scale[i]}" -b:v "${bitrate[i]}" -y output.mp4
done
```

Comment: I think the OP's main issue is how to capture a second array from the same argument list.

Comment: That's one approach. If the values are already in separate strings, though, it can be more convenient to pass them as requested in the question. (I encourage you to post that approach as a second answer, though; you can actually write the script to support both options simultaneously.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find some more information about `getopts` [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial). In short, you can just add `s:` to accept values for parameter `-s`, and just read them in the same way as for parameter `-b`.

Add a nested for-loop to loop through the size values you specify:

```
for rate in "${bitrate[@]}"; do
    for size in "${sizes[@]}"; do
        ...
    done
done
```

For the sake of it, in the below full script implementation, I also added parameter checking that would result in default values for both `-s` and `-b` if they haven't been specified when calling the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "i:b:s:" flag
do
  case "$flag" in
    i) input="$OPTARG" ;;
    b) IFS=, read -a bitrate <<< "$OPTARG" ;;
    s) IFS=, read -a sizes <<< "$OPTARG" ;;
  esac
done

(( ${#bitrate[@]} == 0 )) && bitrate=("1000")
(( ${#sizes[@]} == 0 )) && sizes=("100x100")

for rate in "${bitrate[@]}"; do
    for size in "${sizes[@]}"; do
        ffmpeg -i ${input} -video_size ${size} -b:v ${bitrate} -y output-${rate}-${size}.mp4
    done
done

exit
```